# Computing the second (mis-match) table in the Boyer-Moore String Search Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, discrete-mathematics, string-search

For the Boyer-Moore algorithm to be worst-case linear, the computation of the mis-match table must be O(m). However, a naive implementation would loop through all suffixs O(m) and all positions in that that suffix could go and check for equality... which is O(m<sup>3</sup>)!

Below is the naive implementation of [table building algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Moore_string_search_algorithm#The_second_table). So this question becomes: How can I improve this algorithm's runtime to O(m)?

```
def find(s, sub, no):
    n = len(s)
    m = len(sub)

    for i in range(n, 0, -1):
        if s[max(i-m, 0): i] == sub[max(0, m-i):] and \
            (i-m < 1 or s[i-m-1] != no):
            return n-i

    return n

def table(s):
    m = len(s)
    b = [0]*m

    for i in range(m):
        b[i] = find(s, s[m-i:], s[m-i-1])

    return b

print(table('anpanman'))
```

To put minds at rest, this isn't homework. I'll add revisions when anyone posts ideas for improvements.

Comment: For one thing, use xrange(n,0,-1) and xrange(m) in place of range()... it saves a bit of memory

Comment: Actually the code above is Python 3. See http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/functions.html?highlight=range#range

Comment: How about following the implementation from LiteratePrograms? It seems like it does less preprocessing, but I'm no Boyer-Moore expert. http://en.literateprograms.org/Boyer-Moore_string_search_algorithm_(Python)

Comment: Forgot about the parentheses: http://is.gd/xSEz

Comment: The code in that link is not worst-case O(n) and it only builds the first table (I want to build the second).

Comment: Urghhh... Boyer-Moore.  I hate that algorithm so much.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code under "Preprocessing for the good-suffix heuristics" on [this page](http://www.iti.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/pattern/bmen.htm) builds the good-suffix table in O(n) time. It also explains how the code works.